# Why do I get Workbook Close Runtime error 91?

Tags: excel, vba, xlsm

I want to close the other open workbook via a macro below.
It gives this error:

> Run-Time Error '91': Object Variable or With Block Variable Not Set

```
Sub Macro1()

    Dim wb As Workbook

    Set wb = Application.Workbooks.Open("C:\PmdExcelAddIn.xlsm")
    wb.Close

End Sub
```

Comment: Is there enough time to open the workbook? I always put a DoEvents after open to let the workbook open before doing something else

Comment: Why is the workbook called addin but is a xlsm? Why not make is xlam and install the macro that is on it?

Comment: Why do you open a workbook just to close it?

Comment: Try `Set wb = Application.Workbooks("PmdExcelAddIn.xlsm")` instead of `Set wb = Application.Workbooks.Open("C:\PmdExcelAddIn.xlsm")` .. Looks like the file is already open.

Comment: I tested this code and it works fine for me. Suspect something is not right with file `C:\PmdExcelAddIn.xlsm` being opened and closed.

Comment: If you are recieving that error it means you are failing to set the `wb` object, If you add `If Not wb Is Nothing Then` before you try close I bet you won't get the error. Your address to the file is probably incorrect.

Comment: Does `Msgbox Dir("C:\PmdExcelAddIn.xlsm")` return a value or an empty string?

Comment: Is there any code in `PmdExcelAddIn.xlsm` coded to be executed right after opening the workbook, that makes the workbook close? that would explain variable `wb` failing if the workbook is already closed

Answer (score 0):

If the workbook is open try:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Macro1()

    Dim wb As Workbook

    'Change wb name
    Set wb = Application.Workbooks("PmdExcelAddIn.xlsm")

    wb.Close

End Sub
```